# Свободное позицианирование фрагментов на активити

Tags: android, анимация, android-fragment, android-layout

Работаю с фрагментами.

Хочу сделать анимационное перемещение фрагментов по активити.
К примеру один фрагмент появляется на форме.
Дальше при определенных действиях пользователя этот фрагмент должен плавно подняться в верхнюю часть активити и остаться там.

У меня возникают сразу несколько проблем:

1. На какой разметке это можно сделать?! Абсолютное позиционирование устарело, а остальные только отчасти позволяют это сделать. К примеру, я хочу, чтобы фрагмент перемещался то вверх то вниз, или занимал 30% по высоте от экрана. А над фрагментом либо появлялись другие фрагменты либо исчезали?
2. Как программно сделать один фрагмент по слою выше другого?

Как работает сама анимация, я знаю. Основные проблемы это с системой разметки в Android.

Comment: Вам тут скорей всего с popupWindow надо использовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `FrameLayout` с отступами прекрасно с этим справится.
2. В Андроиде 5 и выше добавили понятие Z-order
   https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html
   В более ранних версиях, придется манипулировать с порядоком добавления в контейнер. Всегда можно View удалить из контейнера и добавить снова на самый верх.